# Encryption and Decryption of a text file

Tags: c#, winforms, encryption, cryptography

Ok so I have a small program that I built in C# winforms that is basically using security cryptology and I am trying to figure out what I did wrong in the code. It will encrypt the text file fine. However, when I paste the encrypted file in the textbox and hit Decrypt, it does not decrypt the file but encrypts it again.

I am wondering if I did something wrong with the code.

```
namespace Encrypted
{
    class Encryptor
    {
        public static string IV = "1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a";
        public static string Key = "1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a";

        public static string Encrypt (string decrypted)
        {
            byte[] textbytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(decrypted);
            AesCryptoServiceProvider endec = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
            endec.BlockSize = 128;
            endec.KeySize = 256;
            endec.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(IV);
            endec.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Key);
            endec.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            endec.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            ICryptoTransform icrypt = endec.CreateEncryptor(endec.Key, endec.IV);
            byte[] enc = icrypt.TransformFinalBlock(textbytes, 0, textbytes.Length);
            icrypt.Dispose();
            return Convert.ToBase64String(enc);
        }

        public static string Decrypted(string encrypted)
        {
            byte[] textbytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(encrypted);
            AesCryptoServiceProvider endec = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
            endec.BlockSize = 128;
            endec.KeySize = 256;
            endec.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(IV);
            endec.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Key);
            endec.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            endec.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            ICryptoTransform icrypt = endec.CreateEncryptor(endec.Key, endec.IV);
            byte[] enc = icrypt.TransformFinalBlock(textbytes, 0,     textbytes.Length);
            icrypt.Dispose();
            return ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(enc);
        }
    }
 }
```

This is the class above and below is the Form1:

```
namespace Encrypted
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnEncrypt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string dir = textBox1.Text;
            Directory.CreateDirectory("data\\" + dir);

            var sw = new StreamWriter("data\\" + dir + "data.ls");

            string enctxt = Encryptor.Encrypt(textBox1.Text);

            sw.WriteLine(enctxt);

            sw.Close();
        }

        private void btnDecrypt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string dir = textBox2.Text;
            Directory.CreateDirectory("data\\" + dir);

            var sw = new StreamWriter("data\\" + dir + "data.ls");

            string enctxt = Encryptor.Decrypted(textBox2.Text);

            sw.WriteLine(enctxt);

            sw.Close();
        }
    }
```

In the Decrypt button do I need to use StreamReader or StreamWriter. Once the encrypted file is in the data.ls I copy it and paste it into the text box for decrypt. However is does not decrypt, it only re-encrypts the file. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: So the `Decrypted` method should be calling `CreateDecryptor` (not `CreateEncryptor`), correct?

Comment: well when I call the     CreateDecryptor    it throws an error, saying that the block is not a full block

Comment: The next most obvious problem is that you are not using the same encoding on the encrypted string. You return a base-64 string from encrypt but then you are using ASCII when encoding in `Decrypted`. You should be encoding using `Convert.FromBase64String` to get `textbytes`.

Comment: @mike  now it throws an error Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Illegal characters in path.

Comment: You are using the input data to create a directory. If that data has characters that can't be used in a path you are out of luck. The way I would design this would be to ask the user for the input data *and* a file name. FWIW, the Encryptor class works fine for me if I make the two changes I suggested.

Comment: the encryptor class works fine, its just the decrypting. However this app is for my own personal use. I usually program speech programs and this is the first I have gotten into crypto. However I can give you the link to the video example I followed and it was for a encrypted login. It worked fine. However I am converting it to a text file, because I want to encrypt my source codes just incase someone gets ahold of my laptop.

Comment: Writing code to learn how stuff works is all well and good but why aren't you using a product written and verified by experts, e.g. BitLocker or VeraCrypt? Good cryptographic security is not a roll your own kind of thing.

Comment: I usually focus all my time in coding Speech Recognition Neural Networks. I have been building a digital system assistant called a comanoid. So my programming is limited when it comes to crypto. But I want my own products because I know there is no pansey work or security leaks.. But I have extensive research and some videos on my website and there is tons of people asking for source codes.. And bitlocker screwed me over.. But here is the video example I was talking about https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cYLX94DR8_Q I think that's the link

Comment: Do you actually expect the `CreateEncryptor` method to decrypt? What do you think the `CreateDecryptor` method does?

Comment: It's a bit odd to convert a `String`, which uses the Unicode character set, to the ASCII encoding of the ASCII character set. The UTF-8 encoding of the Unicode character set would make more sense. If you did intend to restrict the characters to only those shared with the ASCII character set, a check and exception would make that clear and prevent users from experiencing data corruption. Except where ASCII appears in some protocol specifications, its intentional and appropriate use is rare.

Comment: All I am trying to do is encrypt my speech recognition source codes, so "IF" my laptop gets hacked or stolen. They will not be able to view it. Because once this is set I will have the encryption on my dev environment laptop and the decryption on another laptop. So all files will be n a flash drive. So the only way it can decrypted is if you have the decryption program which be disguised as well so you never know its a decryption program. That's all I am trying to do. This is my first rodeo with cryptographic coding.

Comment: @zaph I had it CrateEncryptor at first, because I was following a YouTube video, that how he done it. However, he never showed the decryption side. I tried to follow un-lucky but his way screwed up my program throwing errors left and right. That's why its still encrytor. I have not changed but I know its supposed to be CreateDecrypted. I am using a cell phone and its hard to edit on a cellphone and its auto correct feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you are using the `Decrypted()` also for encrypting the input file by Creating  `Encryptor`. It should Create a `Decryptor` to perform the Decryption operation. This single word change will reverse the process. the [CreateDecryptor Method (Byte[], Byte[])](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342066(v=vs.110).aspx) of `AesCryptoServiceProvider` class will Creates a symmetric AES decryptor object using the specified key and initialization vector (IV).

ie. Change the following line in the `Decrypted()` method,

```
  ICryptoTransform icrypt = endec.CreateDecryptor(endec.Key, endec.IV);
```

Here is a Reference example from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aescryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) and you can see a Working example [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bFvxp8)

Comment: when I do it this way it throws this error    An unhandled exception of type 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException' occurred in System.Core.dll

Additional information: The input data is not a complete block.

Comment: when I use it the way I had it it does not throw any errors

Comment: this is what I have, I changed it like your answer but it does not work.     
     ICryptoTransform icrypt = endec.CreateDecryptor(endec.Key, endec.IV);

Comment: @campnerd : See this reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aescryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: the samples on MSDN shows it in a console app. So they are using CryptoStreamMode.Writer. Now if I look at my code I am using stream writer. Is there a difference? Also, MSDN show the code using static string methods, versus I am using public static string methods. Could this be calling the error. Everything I have done lines up with MSDN but when I follow your sample and instructions I get an error. However before the program ran with no errors.

Comment: you do realize I am doing a winform app and your giving me samples to a console app. Everything your showing me I have done and now my app is screwed up. to where I am going to have to start over.. So since I am having to start over now if I go to with the MSDN to the T. then anyone can decrypt my encrypted file. So now how am I supposed to follow what your saying when your giving me samples to a whole app form?

Comment: @campnerd : this is not a Code writing/ application development service. We can provide sample codes and correct errors if any. Sorry

Comment: I know this is not a code writing service. If my account will quit being banned because people down vote to get reputations and all that you would see I usually have higher rep points. and what I don't understand you told me, this is not a code writing service and the funny thing is I said the exact same thing 5 months ago and I got banned. SO this is not my first rodeo with Stackoverflow. This is the first time I am doing crypto. I don't want you to write the code, its just that what your showing me as samples does not fit what I am needing.

Answer (score 0):

It's not only the mistake of not using CreateDecryptor. You also have to decode the ciphertext string from base64, which is what your encrypt returns.

You are doing this:

1. take string, decode from ASCII to plaintext bytes
2. take plaintext bytes, encrypt to ciphertext bytes
3. take ciphertext bytes, *convert to base64 string*

Then you do this:

1. take string, *decode from ASCII* to ciphertext bytes <-- your mistake!

instead:

1. take string, decode from *base64* to ciphertext bytes
2. take ciphertext bytes, decrypt to plaintext bytes
3. take plaintext bytes, encode to ASCII.

string -> bytes -> encrypted bytes -> base64 -> encrypted bytes -> bytes -> string

Comment: Ok now that makes more sense than what the other guy was saying.. So basically I have the code right just in the wrong order. When I get back home I will see what changes I made. This works perfect on the encryption side. However I got to put the correct order of code for decryption. I thought I done that. I guess I did not eat enough sweet-tarts when I started this..lol

Answer (score 0):

I searched for it and made a program that worked fine with me :)
So...

This is the class

```
   class Encryptor
{
    public static string IV = "1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a";
    public static string Key = "1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a13";

    public static string Encrypt(string decrypted)
    {
        byte[] textbytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(decrypted);
        AesCryptoServiceProvider endec = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
        endec.BlockSize = 128;
        endec.KeySize = 256;
        endec.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(IV);
        endec.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Key);
        endec.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        endec.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        ICryptoTransform icrypt = endec.CreateEncryptor(endec.Key, endec.IV);
        byte[] enc = icrypt.TransformFinalBlock(textbytes, 0, textbytes.Length);
        icrypt.Dispose();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(enc);
    }

    public static string Decrypted(string encrypted)
    {
        byte[] textbytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encrypted);
        AesCryptoServiceProvider endec = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
        endec.BlockSize = 128;
        endec.KeySize = 256;
        endec.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(IV);
        endec.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Key);
        endec.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        endec.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        ICryptoTransform icrypt = endec.CreateDecryptor(endec.Key, endec.IV);
        byte[] enc = icrypt.TransformFinalBlock(textbytes, 0, textbytes.Length);
        icrypt.Dispose();
        return System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(enc);
    }
}
```

...................................

and this is the form`

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string dir = textBox1.Text;
        Directory.CreateDirectory("data\\" + dir);

        var sw = new StreamWriter("data\\" + dir + "data.ls");

        string enctxt = Encryptor.Encrypt(textBox1.Text);

        sw.WriteLine(enctxt);

        sw.Close();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string dir = textBox2.Text;

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Application.StartupPath +"\\data\\"+ dir + "data.ls");
        string line = sr.ReadLine();

        textBox1.Text = Encryptor.Decrypted(Convert.ToString(line));
    }
```

........................

Best regards !